# Why whether $V^TV$ is singular or not could indicate linear dependence or independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, and the textbook I use says that we could determine linear dependence or linear independence by finding whether the matrix $V^TV \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ is singular.

I could not figure why is this. Thank you if you could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $(V^TV)_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$.
For each $i=1,\dots,k$ let

$$w_i=\sum_{m=1}^k\, \langle v_i,v_m\rangle \cdot e_m$$

so that $V^TV$ is the matrix whose $i$-th column is $w_i$.

Now, we have that $V^TV$ is singular if and only if its columns are linearly dependent.
In other words, $V^TV$ is singular if and only if there are $a_i$, not all of them $0$, with $\sum_{i=1}^k\,a_iw_i=0$.

Now, we may rewrite this equality as follows:

\begin{align}
0=\sum_{i=1}^k\,a_iw_i
&=\sum_{i=1}^k\,a_i\left(\sum_{m=1}^k\, \langle v_i,v_m\rangle \cdot e_m\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^k\,e_m\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\, a_i\,\langle v_i,v_m\rangle\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^k\,e_m\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\, \,\langle a_i\,v_i,v_m\rangle\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^k\,e_m\cdot\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i,v_m\right\rangle.
\end{align}

Therefore, $V^TV$ is singular if and only if there are $a_i$, not all of them $0$, with

$$\sum_{m=1}^k\,e_m\cdot\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i,v_m\right\rangle=0.\tag{1}$$

Since $\{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$ is linearly independent, $(1)$ holds if and only if $\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i,v_m\right\rangle=0$ for all $m=1,\dots,k$.

But this is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i=0$.
Indeed, by the linearity of the inner product we have that

\begin{align}\sum_{m=1}^ka_m\cdot\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i,v_m\right\rangle
&=\sum_{m=1}^k\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i,a_m\,v_m\right\rangle\\
&=\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i,\sum_{m=1}^ka_m\,v_m\right\rangle
={\left\lVert\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i\right\rVert}^2.
\end{align}

It follows that $V^TV$ is singular if and only if there are $a_i$, not all of them $0$, with $\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i=0$.
It suffices to note that $\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\,v_i=0$ means precisely that $V=\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: I understand everything except the "why" part, could you please give more details?

Comment: See the edit. Basically, because $\sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i$ is a vector in $S=\text{span}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ that is orthogonal to every $v_j$, linearity of the inner product means it is orthogonal to every vector in $S$ -- including itself! But the only vector orthogonal to itself is the $0$ vector -- it is the only vector for which the norm vanishes.

Comment: I totally understand, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few concepts that are at play here (or at least that's a way I would use to explain this):

1. [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition):

Decompose $V$ as $V = U \Sigma L^T$.

Now, the rank of the matrix $V$ is $rank(V) \leq  min(n,k)$. The number of non-zero elements along the "diagonal" of $\Sigma$ will be equal to the rank, and the remaining will be $0$.

2. [Eigenvalue Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix)

$V^TV = L \Sigma^T U^T U \Sigma L = L \Sigma^T\Sigma L$

This now looks like the Eigenvalue decomposition for $V^TV$. If you calculate $\Sigma^T \Sigma$, you will be able to see how many zeros there are on the diagonal, again depending on the rank, but now the rank of $V^T V$. Notice how we are using the $\Sigma$ from the SVD of $V$, however.

3. Determinant

The determinant of a square matrix is the product of its eigenvalues, and the determinant of a singular matrix is $0$. Also, a singular matrix is not full rank.

So if $V$ were to have linearly dependent vectors, the determinant of $V^TV$ would be $0$.